# Objective-C. Fail to instantiate an object

Tags: objective-c

I have recently started my journey with Objective-C.

In my class KGApp, I have a method `-(void)createArrayOfKGAppQuotes`. In that method:

1. I take the long NSString of quotes and authors and split it into `quotesArrayTemp`.
2. Then I do the loop where,
3. I split each quote and its author and place it to the `tempQuoteArray`
4. Then I am trying to `addObject` to the property `quotesArray` that holds KGQuote objects by instantiating this object with the initializer that takes two NSStrings respectively.

```
-(void)createArrayOfKGAppQuotes {

    NSArray<NSString *> *quotesArrayTemp = [self.stringOfQuotes componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    
    for (NSString *quote in quotesArrayTemp) {
        NSArray *tempQuoteArray = [quote componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        
        [self.quotesArray addObject:[[KGQuote alloc] initWithQuote:[tempQuoteArray objectAtIndex:0] andWithAuthor:[tempQuoteArray objectAtIndex:1]]];
    }
}
```

I am sure that `tempQuoteArray` is being populated and it holds NSStrings. But `quotesArray` goes back as nil.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Add `NSLog()` to see the value. If there is something nil, empty, etc. You can use the debugguer & breakpoints if you prefer, but usually when we begin we prefers printings.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I already did NSLogs in my code. when I do NSLog for quotesArrayTemp, everything it works as it supposed and it prints the elements. When I do NSLog for quotesArray that in my for-loop, it goes back as nil.

Comment: So `quotesArray` is nil? If you print it at the beginning of the method, it will be nil, no? So the issue is that you didn't initialized it.

Comment: Hey, I print it below this line: [self.quotesArray addObject:[[KGQuote alloc] initWithQuote:[tempQuoteArray objectAtIndex:0] andWithAuthor:[tempQuoteArray objectAtIndex:1]]];

Comment: Also, if I would like to print just a property of the first object from that array, I try to do this:
NSLog(@"%@", [[self.quotesArray objectAtIndex:0].author]); 
That does not work. Xcode expects identifier.

Comment: You need to do `self.quotesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]] ;` at some point.

Comment: `KGQuote *quote = [self.quotesArray objectAtIndex:0]; NSString *author = [quote author];`, or with a cast: `NSString *author = [(KGQuote *)[self.quotesArray objectAtIndex:0] author];`

Comment: So the property: @property NSMutableArray<KGQuote *> *quotesArray; will not instantiate itself as an empty array, while I instantiate the whole object in my main?

Comment: Exactly. You declared it, but you didn't initialized it. Imagine you want a custom initialization for it, etc. Here that's an array, but if you have a UIViewController, if you want to init it from the xib, another custom xib, a storyboard, etc. You need to provide its initialization

Comment: Incredible. It works. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: One more question.
In swift, when creating a class, I could have just created a property, an array like this:
var quotesArray [KGQuote] = [], so its instantiated as empty straight away, when a class is instantiated.
is it possible to do so with @property NSMutableArray<KGQuote *> *quotesArray;?